# TFS check in excluded files

Tags: svn, tfs

I have just started using TFS and I run into some issues that I find a bit annoying.

In my "Images" folder i add images through my "File Explorer" in Windows, and in VS I then have to inlcude the files in the project, before I can check them into TFS. I guess that is just how it works.

But are there any settings we can set to make sure TFS check in all files in the solution folder, including the "Excluded in project" files?

Like images, I dont need them to be included in my VS project, but I want them into my SVN/TFS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS 2010, you would have to use the Solution Explorer, right click on the folder your project resides, choose `Add Items to Folder...` to add the external files.

In TFS 2012, the new [Local workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx) mode will detect any changes to your project including external items. External items will be listed in Excluded Changes of the pending changes window.

[image]

Comment: Nice, then I will use VS2012. Thanks :)